# Custom sort array in PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I sort arrays in php by a custom alphabet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350510/how-can-i-sort-arrays-in-php-by-a-custom-alphabet)

For example, i have six words:

banana, apple, love, zasca, japanese, car

Is there a way to sort in alphabetic order, using this custom order: "j, c, z, l, a"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's some rough code to get you started:

Basically, it looks at the first letter of each word in the data array, the checks its position in the `$sortOrder` array.  Letters that aren't in `$sortOrder` get put onto the end in the order appear.

Right off the bat, this is going to break if `$sortOrder` has more than 100,000 items in it.  There are probably other holes too but I figure it's a decent enough example of how [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) works.

```
<?php
function getSortOrder($c) {
    $sortOrder = array("j","c","z","l","a");
    $pos = array_search($c, $sortOrder);

    return $pos !== false ? $pos : 99999;
}

function mysort($a, $b) {
    if( getSortOrder($a[0]) < getSortOrder($b[0]) ) {
        return -1;
    }elseif( getSortOrder($a[0]) == getSortOrder($b[0]) ) {
        return 0;
    }else {
        return 1;
    }
}

$data = array(
    "banana",
    "apple",
    "love",
    "zasca",
    "japanese",
    "car"
);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($data,true) . '</pre>';
usort($data, "mysort");
echo '<pre>' . print_r($data,true) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, I just updated it to use array_search instead. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes check out [this documentation on usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Edit: Sorry I gave you key sort but you want to compare values!

Comment: Links support a good answer but don't constitute a good answer in solitude.  Please improve this post. Stack Exchange doesn't want to be a traffic router, it wants to be the last stop for researchers.