# Re-arrange array elements if they meet a condition

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

The array:

```
array(
  '354' => array( 
             'parent' => 0
           ),

  '370' => array( 
             'parent' => 0
           ),

  '420' => array( 
             'parent' => 354
           ),

)
```

How can I move all elements that have the 'parent' value != 0, just after the element to which the key is the same as that parent value?

For example, the element with the 420 keys above needs to go after the element with the 354 key...

Answer (score 1):

That's impossible in the general case. In your example it would work.

But here's another example:

```
Number | Parent
10     | 1
11     | 1
100    | 10
101    | 10
102    | 10
1000   | 100
1001   | 100
```

So you want that all the three rows `100`, `101`, `102` come directly after the row `10`, which is impossible.

And between row `100` and `101` you probably want the rows `1000` and `1001`, since their parent is `100`.

**[Update]**

So there remain these questions:

- Do you just need the nodes ordered so that each node is defined somewhere before it is used as a parent?
- Do the direct children have to follow their parent directly, oder may there be some other nodes in between?
- Is the parent ID always smaller than the node ID?

Comment: hm.. why do you say it's impossible? I just want to re-arrange the array... The parent value will always point to a existing element key..

Comment: Well, either I didn't understand your question, or maybe your example is too simple. How would you like my example to be arranged? There's more than one possible solution, and I'm not sure which one you want.

Comment: well that's what I want:) all three elements with keys 100, 101, 102 to go after element with key 10. And yes, 1000 and 1001 to go after 100 :) I don't know if it's possible with uasort like someone posted, it looks like u need recursion or something...

Comment: If the `parent` id is always smaller than the array key, you can simply sort the array in two steps: first by the array key (numerically) and then by the parent id (also numerically). Besides, I just noticed that my example was also too simple. See my "answer" for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking at a way to make a flat array have some sort of hierarchie?

This is a very simple case which will do that asuming your children always have a higher id than their parent.

```
<?php
$array = array(
  '354' => array( 
             'parent' => 0
           ),
  '370' => array( 
             'parent' => 0
           ),
  '420' => array( 
             'parent' => 354
           ),
  '550' => array(
             'parent' => 420
           ),
);


/**
 * 
 * This function will convert a flat array with elements to the proper hierarchy structure
 * @param array $array
 */
function hierarchy(&$array) {
    arsort($array);
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if($value['parent'])
        {
            $array[$value['parent']]['children'][$key] = $value;
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    asort($array);
    return $array;
}

(print '<pre>' . print_r(hierarchy($array), true) . '</pre>');
```

Heres a testcase:

http://codepad.org/RT51uOfn

Comment: but they array should remain flat

Comment: Then maybe you're looking for something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350510/how-can-i-sort-arrays-in-php-by-a-custom-alphabet custom sorting in php, though your function would like a