# how to sort multiD array with sube value

Tags: php, arrays

i have array which contains hotels arrays,

- every (hotel) array have (rooms) array that contain rooms data like the price for this room and room number.
- i want to get the five hotels with the lowest rooms price that called **(price_str)**

**important notes :**

Number of arrays for hotels unexpected

Number of arrays for rooms unexpected

i work in this project with php 5.3..so some new php features not work

```
// the first hotel info array
    id:52548
    Le Meridien Heliopolis
    51 Al Orouba Street Heliopolis  Po Box 2928
    stars 5

    rooms 255
//description
    Set in one of the finest residential districts of Cairo, the Le Meridien Heliopolis
    is ideally located near the Cairo International Conference Centre,
    // image
    http://cdn.wego.com/gazo/88/2f1ceaef3b36d83d13bb01b0f413298bb2e42514/137974_B.jpg
// this array contains rooms info in this hotel
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 119-9
                [price_str] => 95
                [currency_code] => USD
                [currency_sym] => US$
                [provider_name] => Le Meridien
                [provider_code] => lemeridien.com
                [ex_tax] => 1
                [is_direct] => 1
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 6-1
                [price_str] => 104
                [currency_code] => USD
                [currency_sym] => US$
                [provider_name] => Booking.com
                [provider_code] => booking.com
                [ex_tax] => 
                [is_direct] => 
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 88-201
                [price_str] => 104
                [currency_code] => USD
                [currency_sym] => US$
                [provider_name] => Wego
                [provider_code] => wego.com
                [ex_tax] => 
                [is_direct] => 
            )

    )

// the second hotel info
    id:52629
    Holidays Express Hotel
    2 Gameat El Dowal El Arabyia St.,Sphinx Square , Mohandessin 
    stars 4
    rooms 
// desciption
    With its central location, Holidays Express Hotel is within easy reach of most
    tourist attractions and business addresses in Cairo.
// image
    http://cdn.wego.com/gazo/43/78be2c05a7069febbfc15b88d40af58cc8871751/7350810_B.jpg

// the rooms info for this hotel
    Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 6-1
// i want to sort by lowest price_str
                [price_str] => 63
                [currency_code] => USD
                [currency_sym] => US$
                [provider_name] => Booking.com
                [provider_code] => booking.com
                [ex_tax] => 
                [is_direct] => 
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 88-201
                [price_str] => 63
                [currency_code] => USD
                [currency_sym] => US$
                [provider_name] => Wego
                [provider_code] => wego.com
                [ex_tax] => 
                [is_direct] => 
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 70-1
                [price_str] => 69
                [currency_code] => USD
                [currency_sym] => US$
                [provider_name] => DHR.com
                [provider_code] => dhr.com
                [ex_tax] => 1
                [is_direct] => 
            )

    )
```

Comment: are u getting the hotel details from database?

Comment: i guess u can use usort for this purpose. Refer this post :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145393/sorting-a-php-array-of-arrays-by-custom-order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- find the lowest price of each hotel, store the price in a array, index by hotel index.
- sort the array by price.
- fetch the top 5 result

#

```
<?php
$price_list = array(); // the lowest price of each hotel stroes in this array, indexed by the index of each hotel in $hotels array

foreach ($hotels->json_data->hotels as $hotel_index => $hotel)
{
    // find out the lowest price of this hotel
    $min_price = 0;
    foreach ($hotel->room_rates as $room)
    {
        if ($min_price == 0 || $room->price_str < $min_price)
        {
            $min_price = $room['price_str'];
        }
    }
    $price_list[$hotel_index] = $min_price;
}

// sort by price
asort($price_list, SORT_NUMERIC);

// fetch the top hotel
$count = 0;
$list = array();
foreach ($price_list as $index => $price)
{
    $list[] = $hotels->json_data->hotels[$index];
    $count++;
    if ($count > 5)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: the main variable that contain all this data called .. $hotels->json_data->hotels..how to use this in your code?

Comment: show the array which posted in my question...the problem is i cant know price_str before loop the hotels first..so why you do this $price_list = array();

Comment: `$price_list` to store the lowest price room in each hotel.

Comment: i doesn't make a sense.. because you supposed that i know the price ..the truth is i cant know the price before loop all hotels first.!!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38011/discussion-between-user1080247-and-srain)