# Sort array by specified ID's?

Tags: php, sorting

I have the following array that indicates the order on how to sort the DATA array:

```
 $PARENT_ID_ORDER = array(1, 3, 2);
```

Here's the DATA array, which contains PARENT_ID key, I want to sort by PARENT_ID key using my PARENT_ID_ORDER:

```
 $DATA = array (
     array (
        'PARENT_ID' => 2;
     ),
     array (
        'PARENT_ID' => 2;
     ),
     array (
        'PARENT_ID' => 1;
     ),
     array (
        'PARENT_ID' => 3;
     ),
     array (
        'PARENT_ID' => 1;
     ),
     array (
        'PARENT_ID' => 2;
     ),
     array (
        'PARENT_ID' => 2;
     )
 );
```

The expected output:

```
 array(
        [0] => Element Object
            (
                [PARENT_ID] => 1,
            ),
        [1] => Element Object
            (
                [PARENT_ID] => 1,
            ),
        [2] => Element Object
            (
                [PARENT_ID] => 3,
            ),
        [3] => Element Object
            (
                [PARENT_ID] => 2,
            ),
        [4] => Element Object
            (
                [PARENT_ID] => 2,
            ),
        [5] => Element Object
            (
                [PARENT_ID] => 2,
            ),
        [6] => Element Object
            (
                [PARENT_ID] => 2,
            )
 );
```

How can I provide my order array to sort function so it gets sorted this way? Thanks!

Comment: Please see this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145393/sorting-a-php-array-of-arrays-by-custom-order

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php.
You can use this along with binary search or inbuilt array_search if array is small

Comment: Or as an alternative to binary search / array_search, array_flip the $PARENT_ID_ORDER array and then index into it and compare the values.