# PHP - Sort associative array based on predifined order of keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [Lhgee] => some object
    [V4ooa] => some object
    [N0la] => some object
)
```

I need to sort this array in to this order: V4ooa, Lhgee, N0la
so after sorting the array would like this:

```
Array
(
    [V4ooa] => some object
    [Lhgee] => some object
    [N0la] => some object
)
```

I've looked at uasort and I'm pretty sure it's what I need (as I need to keep all the data against the relevant array) but can't work out how to acheive this with associative arrays as all the examples seem to use integer indexes.
Thanks

Comment: How would this be sorted since L is not between N or V in the alphabet ? Are you sure of your wanted output ?

Comment: That is exactly my problem...Yes the output needs to be in this order

Comment: So it's not a logical order at all, how would you expect any function to guess the order you want ? Don't you have any other way to sort your array, a property in each of your array objects maybe ?

Comment: I don't need it to "guess" the order. I'm giving it the order. (or that's the plan anyway!).

Comment: You just deal with this 3 keys or maybe there will be more ? Only letters or possibly integers in the keys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to check this

```
$order = array('V4ooa', 'Lhgee', 'N0la');
$array = array
    (
        ['Lhgee'] => some object
        ['V4ooa'] => some object
        ['N0la'] => some object
    );

$orderedArray = sortArray($array, $order);

var_dump($orderedArray);

function sortArray(array $array, array $order) {
    $ordered = array();
    foreach($order as $key) {
        if(array_key_exists($key,$array)) {
            $ordered[$key] = $array[$key];
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $ordered;
}
```

**UPDATE**

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-by-keys-based-on-another-array)
**and** 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145393/sorting-a-php-array-of-arrays-by-custom-order)

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to achieve! Just needed to change function `sortArray(array $array, array $order)` to `function sortArray(array $array, array $orderArray)` - Thank you :)