# what's the best way to order an array using another in PHP?

Tags: php

Suppose I have an array that I want to sort, and the order is not something computable, but rather, given by another array which lists the keys in the desired order:

```
$ordering_array = [
    'c',
    'a',
    'k',
    'e',
];
```

As an added complication, not all of these keys might be present in my array to sort:

```
$given_array = [
    'a' => 'value',
    'c' => 'value',
    'e' => 'value',
];
```

What is the cleanest / quickest way to achieve this?

My method is:

```
$new_array = array_fill_keys($ordering_array, NULL);

foreach ($given_array as $key => $value) {
  $new_array[$key] = $value;
}

$new_array = array_filter($new_array);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: why not post in code review ?

Comment: @C2486 Would get closed for being example code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145393/sorting-a-php-array-of-arrays-by-custom-order

Comment: Just so you know, `array_filter()` is going to kill all `falsey` values with extreme prejudice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an Array by keys based on another Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-by-keys-based-on-another-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the `foreach` with [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)

```
$new_array = array_fill_keys($ordering_array, NULL);
$new_array = array_replace($new_array, $given_array);
$new_array = array_filter($new_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
$filteredKeys = array_intersect_key(array_flip($ordering_array), $given_array);
$outputArray = array_merge($filteredKeys, $given_array);
```

Comment: @C2486 fixed it, please check it now

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_merge()` or `array_replace` at the place of foreach, both worked

Try this:

```
$ordering_array = ['c', 'a', 'k', 'e'];
$given_array = ['a' => 'value', 'c' => 'value', 'e' => 'value'];

$new_array = array_fill_keys($ordering_array, NULL);

$new_array = array_merge($new_array, $given_array);
                       OR
$new_array = array_replace($new_array, $given_array);

$new_array = array_filter($new_array);
```

Comment: What you have changed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50982247/2815635) ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a oneliner that solves it:

```
$ordering_array = ['c', 'a', 'k', 'e'];
$given_array = ['a' => 'value', 'c' => 'value', 'e' => 'value'];
$outputArray = array_merge(array_intersect_key(array_flip($ordering_array), $given_array), $given_array);
print_r($outputArray);
```

@rkj was close, but this is how it's done

Test here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/95b30f6e402b1afdb18867471888ff8ba38867de

Answer (score 0):

try using [uksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php),

[demo](https://eval.in/1026321)

```
<?php 
    $ordering_array  = [
        'c',
        'a',
        'k',
        'e',
    ];
    $given_array  = [
        'a' => 'value-a',
        'c' => 'value-c',
        'e' => 'value-e',
    ];

    uksort($given_array , function ($a, $b) use ($ordering_array) {

        $pos_a = array_search($a,$ordering_array);
        $pos_b = array_search($b,$ordering_array);
        return $pos_a - $pos_b;
    });

    var_dump($given_array );
```

Comment: If you flip the ordering_array you can throw away the array_search lines, and change the return to: `return $ordering_array[$a] - $ordering_array[$b];`

Answer (score 0):

Simple and explicit:

```
<?php    
$ordering_array = [
    'c',
    'a',
    'k',
    'e',
];

$given_array = [
    'a' => 'valuea',
    'c' => 'valuec',
    'e' => 'valuee',
];

foreach($ordering_array as $K)
    if(array_key_exists($K, $given_array))
        $ordered[$K] = $given_array[$K];

var_export($ordered);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'c' => 'valuec',
  'a' => 'valuea',
  'e' => 'valuee',
)
```

You might be able to shave off a byte or two with `isset($given_array[$K])` if the data allows.