# Sort elements in each row based on multiple rules comparing associative keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, usort

I've a multidimensional array and want to sort its sub-arrays by their keys in a custom order where I have some fixed positions and some relative positions.

The array looks like this:

```
$array = [
    [
        "ARRIVAL" => '2022-03-08',
        "INFO" => "TEST",
        "V1_PROZ_WET" => 7,
        "V1_ABS_WET" => 200,
        "V1_PROZ" => 4,
        "V1_ABS" => 150,
        "V2_PROZ_WET" => 10,
        "V2_ABS_WET" => 250,
        "V2_PROZ" => 5,
        "V2_ABS" => 180,
        "BEZ" => "TEST",
        "WET_TOTAL" => 500,
        "DRY_TOTAL" => 300
    ],
    [
        "ARRIVAL" => '2022-03-07',
        "INFO" => "TEST",
        "V1_PROZ_WET" => 7,
        "V1_ABS_WET" => 200,
        "V1_PROZ" => 4,
        "V1_ABS" => 150,
        "V2_PROZ_WET" => 10,
        "V2_ABS_WET" => 250,
        "V2_PROZ" => 5,
        "V2_ABS" => 180,
        "BEZ" => "TEST",
        "WET_TOTAL" => 500,
        "DRY_TOTAL" => 300
    ],
    [
        "ARRIVAL" => '2022-03-06',
        "INFO" => "TEST",
        "V1_PROZ_WET" => 7,
        "V1_ABS_WET" => 200,
        "V1_PROZ" => 4,
        "V1_ABS" => 150,
        "V2_PROZ_WET" => 10,
        "V2_ABS_WET" => 250,
        "V2_PROZ" => 5,
        "V2_ABS" => 180,
        "BEZ" => "TEST",
        "WET_TOTAL" => 500,
        "DRY_TOTAL" => 300
    ],
];
```

I want to sort it in following order:

```
$sortOrder = [
    "INFO",         //fixed pos 1
    "BEZ",          //fixed pos 2
    "WET_TOTAL",    //fixed pos 3
    "DRY_TOTAL",    //fixed pos 4
    "_PROZ",        //all dry percentage values
    "_ABS",         //all dry abs values
    "_PROZ_WET",    //all wet percentage values
    "_ABS_WET"      //all wet abs values
];
```

An expected output of a sub-array would be:

```
[
    "INFO" => "TEST",
    "BEZ" => "TEST",
    "WET_TOTAL" => 500,
    "DRY_TOTAL" => 300,
    "V1_PROZ" => 4,
    "V2_PROZ" => 5,
    "V1_ABS" => 150,
    "V2_ABS" => 180,
    "V1_PROZ_WET" => 7,
    "V2_PROZ_WET" => 10,
    "V1_ABS_WET" => 200,
    "V2_ABS_WET" => 250,
    "ARRIVAL" => '2022-03-06'
]
```

I've seen PHP's [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.usort.php) is capable of doing custom sort functions, but I'm stuck because I can't get it running.

This [SO-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11158693/7195155) gave me some good inputs of how I can do custom sorting for multidimensional arrays but I need to sort them by the keys and don't have an "id" key where I can always look at.

Here is a [fiddle](https://paiza.io/projects/79NGuO7h5NRzitbru3YQUA) as playground.

Comment: `//all dry percentage values` - does "all" in there mean you also want to accumulate some data at the same time? Combining multiple input records into one? Then this would be more than just _sorting_ ...

Comment: @CBroe - sorry, I wasn't clear about that, please have a look  at my updated "expected output"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate and modify-by-reference as you call `uksort()` on each row.

Fallback to lesser prioritized criteria using the Elvis operator.

If your PHP version doesn't yet offer arrow functions, you'll need to adjust the script to use long-handed function syntax.

If your PHP version doesn't yet offer `str_contains()`, you'll need to swap these calls out for long-winded `strpos() !== false` checks.

This kind of boolean-based sorting algorithm can trick developers that are new to sorting.  When the spaceship operator compares two boolean values, it treats `false` as `0` and `true` as `1`.  In other words, if you use ASC sorting, then the `false` records come before the `true` records.  If you want the opposite sorting direction, then you swap the position of `$a` and `$b` in the expression.  `$b <=> $a` means DESC sorting.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/h76W2))

```
foreach ($array as &$row) {
    uksort($row, fn($a, $b) => 
        ($b === 'INFO') <=> ($a === 'INFO')
        ?: ($b === 'BEZ') <=> ($a === 'BEZ')
        ?: ($b === 'WET_TOTAL') <=> ($a === 'WET_TOTAL')
        ?: ($b === 'DRY_TOTAL') <=> ($a === 'DRY_TOTAL')
        ?: ($a === 'ARRIVAL') <=> ($b === 'ARRIVAL')
        ?: str_contains($a, '_WET') <=> str_contains($b, '_WET')
        ?: str_contains($b, '_PROZ') <=> str_contains($a, '_PROZ')
        ?: str_contains($b, '_ABS') <=> str_contains($a, '_ABS')
        ?: $a <=> $b
    );
}    
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'INFO' => 'TEST',
    'BEZ' => 'TEST',
    'WET_TOTAL' => 500,
    'DRY_TOTAL' => 300,
    'V1_PROZ' => 4,
    'V2_PROZ' => 5,
    'V1_ABS' => 150,
    'V2_ABS' => 180,
    'V1_PROZ_WET' => 7,
    'V2_PROZ_WET' => 10,
    'V1_ABS_WET' => 200,
    'V2_ABS_WET' => 250,
    'ARRIVAL' => '2022-03-08',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'INFO' => 'TEST',
    'BEZ' => 'TEST',
    'WET_TOTAL' => 500,
    'DRY_TOTAL' => 300,
    'V1_PROZ' => 4,
    'V2_PROZ' => 5,
    'V1_ABS' => 150,
    'V2_ABS' => 180,
    'V1_PROZ_WET' => 7,
    'V2_PROZ_WET' => 10,
    'V1_ABS_WET' => 200,
    'V2_ABS_WET' => 250,
    'ARRIVAL' => '2022-03-07',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'INFO' => 'TEST',
    'BEZ' => 'TEST',
    'WET_TOTAL' => 500,
    'DRY_TOTAL' => 300,
    'V1_PROZ' => 4,
    'V2_PROZ' => 5,
    'V1_ABS' => 150,
    'V2_ABS' => 180,
    'V1_PROZ_WET' => 7,
    'V2_PROZ_WET' => 10,
    'V1_ABS_WET' => 200,
    'V2_ABS_WET' => 250,
    'ARRIVAL' => '2022-03-06',
  ),
)
```