# Custom collation with php using usort

Tags: php, usort

I'm trying to sort an array by a custom alphabet (international names, none of the Collator locales put them in exactly the order that I want).

I've stolen some code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350510/how-can-i-sort-arrays-in-php-by-a-custom-alphabet) and have.

```
 function compare_by_alphabet($str1, $str2){
     $alphabet = "AaÀàÁáÂâÅåÃãÄäÆæBbCcÇçDdÐðEeÈèÉéÊêËëFfGgHhIiÌìÍíÎîÏïJjKkLlMmNnÑñOoÒòÓóÔôÕõÖöØøPpQqRrSsßŠšTtUuÙùÚúÛûÜüVvWwXxYyŸÿÝýZzŽžÞþ0123456789";
     $l1 = strlen($str1);
     $l2 = strlen($str2);
     $c = min($l1, $l2);

     for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++)
     {
         $s1 = substr($str1, $i, 1);
         $s2 = substr($str2, $i, 1);
         if ($s1===$s2) continue;
         $i1 = strpos($alphabet, $s1);
         if ($i1===false) continue;
         $i2 = strpos($alphabet, $s2);
         if ($i2===false) continue;
         if ($i2===$i1) continue;
         if ($i1 < $i2) return -1;
         else return 1;
     }
     if ($l1 < $l2) return -1;
     elseif ($l1 > $l2) return 1;
     return 0;
 }
```

When I try

```
$names=["Schön","Åsberg","Zierer","Ås","Žižek","Schon","Asber"];
usort($names, 'compare_by_alphabet');
```

I get `["Asber","Ås","Åsberg","Schön","Schon","Žižek","Zierer"]` - the two Schon's are the wrong was around, as are Žižek and Zierer.

I'm missing something here. Can someone explain why this isn't behaving as expected, please? Or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard PHP string functions are not multibyte compatible. In your example the strings and the alphabet however contain multibyte characters (most modern php editors will use utf-8 as default [encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding)). For example, À is actually represented by 2 bytes in utf-8.

Run the following to verify that:

```
php > echo strlen("À");
2
```

Use [multibyte string](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) functions to solve the problem.

After applying this, the code is:

```
function compare_by_alphabet($str1, $str2) {

    $alphabet = "AaÀàÁáÂâÅåÃãÄäÆæBbCcÇçDdÐðEeÈèÉéÊêËëFfGgHhIiÌìÍíÎîÏïJjKkLlMmNnÑñOoÒòÓóÔôÕõÖöØøPpQqRrSsßŠšTtUuÙùÚúÛûÜüVvWwXxYyŸÿÝýZzŽžÞþ0123456789";
    $l1 = mb_strlen($str1);
    $l2 = mb_strlen($str2);
    $c = min($l1, $l2);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++)
    {
        $s1 = mb_substr($str1, $i, 1);
        $s2 = mb_substr($str2, $i, 1);
        if ($s1===$s2) continue;
        $i1 = mb_strpos($alphabet, $s1);
        if ($i1===false) continue;
        $i2 = mb_strpos($alphabet, $s2);
        if ($i2===false) continue;


    if ($i2===$i1) continue;
        if ($i1 < $i2) return -1;
        else return 1;
    }
    if ($l1 < $l2) return -1;
    elseif ($l1 > $l2) return 1;
    return 0;
}

$names=["Schön","Åsberg","Zierer","Ås","Žižek","Schon","Asber"];
usort($names, 'compare_by_alphabet');
var_dump($names);
```

and the result

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>string(5) "Asber"
  [1]=>string(3) "Ås"
  [2]=>string(7) "Åsberg"
  [3]=>string(5) "Schon"
  [4]=>string(6) "Schön"
  [5]=>string(6) "Zierer"
  [6]=>string(7) "Žižek"
}
```

Comment: I did not know that! Thanks so much, appreciate it.